# Hello I want to create a before insert that looks if the value is on another table before inserting

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert

I have a database for hospitals and I have a table for patients and one table for appointments. I need to create a trigger that if someone wants to add a person on the appointments table that person must be on the patient table before inserting on the appointments table.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely what [**foreign key constraints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) were invented for. You'd want to create a **foreign key** on the `appointments` table's field that references the **primary key** field of the `patient` table. This will enforce that the person is a `patient` before there can be an `appointment` created for them.

Note that a **foreign key constraint** will likely be more performant than a **trigger** in this scenario as well. For more information and examples on **foreign key constraints**, please read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).